Qt app deployment with Qt5 on an M1 Macbook
I have an app that is written using Qt 5.6.3 under Linux that compiles and runs under Linux and Windows as stand alone apps. I can compile it and run it on an M1 Mac, it compiles using x86 gcc which is OK because it's very simple and people can run it under Roesetta on Arm silicon.
However, following the deployment instructions for MacOS apps is says that you need to go to the build directory and use  macdeployqt with the .app file that is created in the build directory.
There is no .app file though.
Various articles say the app file should be created by default and if you don't want it, you have to disable it, so I can't see why it's not being created.
I also can't debug on the Mac, am wondering whether this is all symptomatic of this underlying issue. I can run the app using Qt Creator and it works fine, but I need to create a stand alone executable.
I have seen some instructions saying that Qt6 runs natively on Arm silicon for Mac OS, but I am using Qextserial port which doesn't work on Qt6, so need this to work on Qt5 and anyway, it's not totally necessary to have a Arm app.
Is there a common issue with creating the .app file with Qt creator? Is there any more information I can supply to try and track this down? I have Googled this issue of an .app bundle not being created, but can't find anything that indicates why this wouldn't happen.
Not sure whether things are even further complicated by the fact that the Qt 5.6.3 install says to install xcode 5.0, but of course, Apple being Apple, won't let you run really old versions of xcode and would only allow me to use the latest version.
FWIW am using Mac  OS 13.0 - Ventura.

I have no solution for you, but I would strongly consider switching to the latest Qt6 and Qt Serial Port module (also remember to check licensing)...
